# How to get index path row of current section if the previous section is collapsed and has 0 rows

Tags: ios

I am using TLIndexPathCollapsible.
Link: https://github.com/wtmoose/TLIndexPathTools

Now I have 2 sections (A and B), 3 rows for each section (a b c). If I expand A and B and I use this:

```
NSInteger rowNumber = 0;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < indexPath.section; i++) {
    rowNumber += [self tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
    NSLog(@"number: %ld",(long)rowNumber);
    NSLog(@"rows in previous section %ld",(long)[tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i]);

}

rowNumber += indexPath.row;
```

It works.

But when I collapsed section A and tap on (section B row a). Because the previous section (section A) is collapsed and has no rows therefore, it returns 0. 
I am using one array to store.
How do i loop through section A and + 1 to get indexPath.row =3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea with TLIPT is that you use a `TLIndexPathDataModel` to store your data items and then the `TLIndexPathDataModel` APIs let you easily convert indexPaths to data item and vise versa. So if you're using `TLCollapsibleTableViewController`, you'd do something like this:

```
id myDataItem = [self.indexPathController.dataModel itemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

If you need to find the index in an external array, then you can do this:

```
NSInteger index = [myArray indexOfObject:myDataItem];
```